# angular material is not working properly in angular9

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, html5-canvas, angular9

I am using material form field but its not working properly , i have imported respective modules also.
don't have any console error also.
here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "online-shop",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build ",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/core": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31",
        "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/localize": "^9.1.11",
        "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/router": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
        "angular-image-slider": "0.0.9",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "mdb-cli": "^1.1.29",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.9",
        "@angular/cli": "^10.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0-rc.6",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.9.5"
    }
}
```

[this is my output of mat form field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgjqO.png)

Comment: It's look like you forget import in your scss `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`

Comment: Checkout [Getting Started with Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add import link to your css/scss file or according to me just add inside styles.css to make it global for angular project because without importing Angular Material doesn't know what theme should apply.
Import link : `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`
Or You can another theme which you refer from Official angular material website [Click here for Angular Material website](https://v9.material.angular.io/guide/theming)